# titanium appcelerator windows phone modules

Tags: windows, windows-phone, titanium, appcelerator

Is there a possibility to have some links to marketplace or github repositories about the titanium appcelerator windows phone modules?

I am looking for a facebook and barcode scanner, but also thinking about my future needs in windows phone titanium app development

Comment: At the moment there do not seem to be any modules around. The guide to develop modules for WP8 is marked as deprecated. So I guess you cannot find any modules at all. Maybe you should consider developing natively?

Comment: Yes, sure. When you develop with titanium you write the code once and just fix here and there to let it compile for this or that platform. personally, don't have the time to write apps natively 3 times (or 2 if I decide to write once for android/ios with titanium). So, maybe I just have to wait.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you can use regular CommonJS modules to talk to any API directly.

See: https://appcelerator.github.io/appc-docs/latest/#!/guide/Windows_Runtime_Direct_API_Access

Answer (score 0):

At the moment no marketplace for Windows as far as I know, but there's documentation on how to create Titanium module for Windows natively: [Windows Module Development Guide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Windows_Module_Development_Guide)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.